# Fit text in a rectangle using SkiaSharp

Tags: drawtext, skiasharp

I need to draw text to fill (i.e. be the largest sensible size which fits in) a rectangle. How can I do this? I can't see any methods to scale/fit the text - so I'm assuming (hopefully incorrectly) that I'm going to have to set a font size and measure to see if it fits, and adjust the font size accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a super old question, but I may as well answer it for anyone else wanting to know how to do this efficiently.

I recently had to do this for a project of mine. This is what I came up with.

To clarify:

> Sector Size: The max length-ways size of the text.

> Max Font: The max font size we want to test.

The comments explain how this works.

```cs
public float GetMaxFontSize(double sectorSize, SKTypeface typeface, string text, float degreeOfCertainty = 1f, float maxFont = 100f)
{
   var max = maxFont; // The upper bound. We know the font size is below this value
   var min = 0f; // The lower bound, We know the font size is equal to or above this value
   var last = -1f; // The last calculated value.
   float value;
   while (true)
   {
      value = min + ((max - min) / 2); // Find the half way point between Max and Min
      using (SKFont ft = new SKFont(typeface, value))
      using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint(ft))
      {
         if (paint.MeasureText(text) > sectorSize) // Measure the string size at this font size
         {
            // The text size is too large
            // therefore the max possible size is below value
            last = value;
            max = value;
         }
         else
         {
            // The text fits within the area
            // therefore the min size is above or equal to value
            min = value;

            // Check if this value is within our degree of certainty
            if (Math.Abs(last - value) <= degreeOfCertainty)
            return last; // Value is within certainty range, we found the best font size!

            //This font difference is not within our degree of certainty
            last = value;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In my use case, it takes 7 steps to calculate a font size of 54.68px, with an average execution duration over 10000 cycles of 250 ticks (0.025ms) with a degree of certainty of 1px.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a slightly inefficient method for doing this starting with a small TextSize and increasing it and measuring until it doesn't fit in the rectangle - then taking the last size which fits.

To make this efficient, I then cache the TextSize for a given control size.

Not ideal, but it works well!

Comment: Another way might be to use some algorithm. For example, measure text at a smaller size, then work out the required size. As the text size is just simply the text height, you can work it out with basic math. Assume text size of 12 has a width of 100. If the total width available is 250, then 250/100=2.5, thus, 12*2.5=30. The probably text size is 30. Most text scales linearly, but even if not, you can work from there up/down depending. Just a guess.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. However, my loop rather than algorithm works nicely and is pretty efficient with the cacheing.

Comment: Did you look at the `SKPaint.MeasureText(string text, ref SKRect bounds)` method? It will give you the bounds of the text you want to draw using the current paint settings you have. That way you get both the width and height at the same time. You can then iteratively refine the text size of the paint to get the text to auto-fit to your rectangle as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the string at any font size, measure the width, and then use the ratio to determine the font size that would fit within your rect.

Font Size 20 = Text Width of 100

To fit in a width of 50 = 50/100 * 20 = Font size of 10